# Assigning number code to a character vector

Tags: r

Let us consider a matrix X with two columns (city name and city code)

```
x1=c('CITYAA','CITYBB','CITYCC')
x2=c(101,201,301)
```

I have another vector of city names(Y) which are given in lower and upper case format:

```
Y=c('Cityaa','Citybb','Cityaa','Citycc','Cityaa', 'Citybb')
```

I want a vector (Z) which assigns city code to the above vector Y (according to X).

```
Z= 101 201 101 301 101 201.
```

I am stuck at the upper and lower case matching.

Comment: you can use `tolower()` or `toupper()` to convert all city names to a single case

Comment: Your example input and output (Z) don't match.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have corrected my mistake. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use factors, playing with levels and labels:

```
as.numeric(as.character(factor(toupper(Y),x1,x2)))
# [1] 101 201 101 301 101 201
```